# Firefox fails with smooth scroll "Go to top"-button

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I'm using an "Go top top"-button with a smooth scroll-effect on my page (the arrow to the right):
http://itu.dk/people/mbul/buch/project.html

```
<body id="gototop">

<a href="#gototop"><img class="nav_gototop" src="img/gototop.png" alt="Go to top"></a>

.nav_gototop{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 2.5em;
    z-index: 999;
    }
```

It works perfectly in Chrome but in Firefox it goes to the top but then jumps a bit down to the header - I can't figure out why. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hmm, I just tested it in Firefox and it works fine for me. Are you on the latest version?

Comment: Works fine for me in firefox as well.

Comment: I see it too - firefox version 27.0.1 ... body tag seems to start 150 pixels below top of the page. Can't figure it out though sorry..

Comment: Okay, that's pretty strange. It works in my Firefox browser now? But hasn't worked the last 50 times I've tried and I haven't changed anything? Thanks for your comments though!